# Subtracting two columns from two different temp tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to compare data from the previous year and the current year parameter. I created three temp tables called `#currentyear`, `#previous_year`, and `#comparison_over_previous_year`.

`#currentyear` data is pulling from a stored procedure and I want to pull the previous year data from the stored procedure as well. When trying to pass a `DATEADD` function while executing a stored procedure, T-SQL doesn't like it. For now, I passed a static data in there.

I want to subtract the Money field from `#currentyear` temp table and the `#previous_year` temp table but I am having a tough time.

My code so far is below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#currentyear') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #currentyear

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#previousyear') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #previousyear

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#comparison_over_previous_year') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #comparison_over_previous_year

CREATE TABLE #currentyear
(
     [Date] DATE,
     [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
     [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
     [begofmonth] DATE 
)

CREATE TABLE #previousyear
(
     [Date] DATE,
     [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
     [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
     [begofmonth] DATE 
)

CREATE TABLE #comparison_over_previous_year
(
     [Date] DATE,
     [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
     [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
     [begofmonth] DATE 
)

INSERT INTO #currentyear
    EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] 
                  @StartDate = '20160101', @EndDate = '20161130', 
                  @ResEQCarrierCd = 'Palomar'

INSERT INTO #previousyear
    EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] 
           --DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@StartDate) = '20160101'
           --DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@EndDate) = '20161130'
           @StartDate = '20150101', **--Using this static value from now as the script above is not playing nice**
           @EndDate = '20151130', @ResEQCarrierCd = 'Palomar'

INSERT INTO #comparison_over_previous_year
    SELECT 
        cy.[Date], cy.[Carrier],
        cy.[Direct Ceded Written Premium] - py.[Direct Ceded Written Premium],
        cy.[begofmonth]
    FROM
        #currentyear cy
    JOIN 
        #previousyear py ON py.[Carrier] = cy.[Carrier]

----Selects the data in order to dump into SSRS
SELECT *
FROM #comparison_over_previous_year
```

SO I have two problems here:

- one is that the `DATEADD` function cannot be passed through `EXEC` statement
- and two is that I have been trying to subtract the value of `[Direct Ceded Written Premium]` columns from `#currentyear` and the `#previous_year` tables. Looks like I would need to group by carrier and begofmonth. Last year may not have all carriers for each month. For example, the month of januray 2015 may not have palomar as a carrier but january 2016 would. So they would not have to be subtracted. if palomar exists on both years, then it would be subtracted. Hope that makes sense.

[image: 2016 DATA]
[image: 2016 DATA]

Here is the outcome that I want to output in SSRS when I export it to excel:

[image: Output]

Comment: This is two questions.  Pick one for this post, edit the post accordingly - pick another for a second post.  These feel like they're probably duplicates as well, so make sure you check to see that these questions haven't been asked and answered already.

Comment: It looks like you're using DATEADD incorrectly as a parameter.  You would want to use it like `@StartDate = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,'20160101')`.

Comment: @danfield There are no duplicates. My data set from my other stored procedure gives me what I want for the current year. What I want from this select statement that will turn into a stored procedure is to subtract one column field to another.

Comment: @Jerrad the paramater that I am using is from another stored proc. I simply cannot change the value there as it would mess with the ssrs report that's using it

Comment: @Lisbon My point is, I'm not sure what you're doing with the `= '20160101' ` in the parameter list.

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining the previous year with more than just the `Carrier` when you insert into the `comparison_over_previous_year` table?

Comment: @Jerrad that is the parameter from the stored procedure that I am calling it from. I have a parameter of atStartDate, atEndDate, and atResEQCarrierCd in the stored procedure that I am calling it from. I am simply just passing the parameter of = '20160101' for now so I have a result set.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I don't think so since the inserted values in the date columns are different due to the difference in years.

Comment: Can you show some sample data from all of the tables?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Uploaded two different data sets. So I am trying to find the difference between direct ceded written premium from 2016 and 2015 per carrier.

Comment: Showing what you want the expected outcome to be can be helpful too.

Comment: @pmbAustin in the above image, I want the direct ceded written premium column values to be subtracted from 2016 to 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a static variable in your code and set it where you need it?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#currentyear') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #currentyear

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#previousyear') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #previousyear

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#comparison_over_previous_year') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #comparison_over_previous_year

CREATE TABLE #currentyear
(
     [Date] DATE,
     [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
     [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
     [begofmonth] DATE 
)

CREATE TABLE #previousyear
(
     [Date] DATE,
     [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
     [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
     [begofmonth] DATE 
)

CREATE TABLE #comparison_over_previous_year
(
     [Date] DATE,
     [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
     [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
     [begofmonth] DATE 
)

DECLARE @start datetime, @end datetime

--variables to hold dates in procs
set @start = '20160101'
set @end = '20161130'

INSERT INTO #currentyear
    EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] 
                  @StartDate = @start, @EndDate = @end, 
                  @ResEQCarrierCd = 'Palomar'

--reset them to -1 year of themselves
set @start = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@start)
set @end = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@end)

INSERT INTO #previousyear
    EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] 

           @StartDate = @start,
           @EndDate = @end

INSERT INTO #comparison_over_previous_year
    SELECT 
        cy.[Date], cy.[Carrier],
        cy.[Direct Ceded Written Premium] - py.[Direct Ceded Written Premium],
        cy.[begofmonth]
    FROM
        #currentyear cy
    JOIN 
        #previousyear py ON py.[Carrier] = cy.[Carrier]

----Selects the data in order to dump into SSRS
SELECT *
FROM #comparison_over_previous_y
```

**However**, your subtraction that you are trying to accomplish relies on only 1 row for each date for each carrier. You should alter your procedure to aggregate the data before you insert it, but here I am doing it into another temp table so you don't have to change the proc.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#currentyear') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #currentyear

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#previousyear') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #previousyear

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#currentyearAggregate') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #currentyearAggregate

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#previousyearAggregate') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #previousyearAggregate

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#comparison_over_previous_year') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #comparison_over_previous_year

CREATE TABLE #currentyear
(
        [Date] DATE,
        [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
        [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
        [begofmonth] DATE 
)

--New Temp Table to hold Aggregated Data
CREATE TABLE #currentyearAggregate
(
        [Date] DATE,
        [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
        [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
        [begofmonth] DATE 
)

CREATE TABLE #previousyear
(
        [Date] DATE,
        [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
        [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
        [begofmonth] DATE 
)

--New Temp Table to hold Aggregated Data
CREATE TABLE #previousyearAggregate
(
        [Date] DATE,
        [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
        [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
        [begofmonth] DATE 
)

CREATE TABLE #comparison_over_previous_year
(
        [Date] DATE,
        [Carrier] VARCHAR(100),
        [Direct Ceded Written Premium] MONEY,
        [begofmonth] DATE 
)

DECLARE @start datetime, @end datetime

--variables to hold dates in procs
set @start = '20160101'
set @end = '20161130'

INSERT INTO #currentyear
    EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] 
                    @StartDate = @start, @EndDate = @end, 
                    @ResEQCarrierCd = 'Palomar'

--reset them to -1 year of themselves
set @start = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@start)
set @end = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@end)

INSERT INTO #previousyear
    EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] 
            @StartDate = @start,
            @EndDate = @end

--Sum up the premiums for each day
INSERT INTO #previousyearAggregate
    SELECT
        [Date],
        [Carrier],
        SUM([Direct Ceded Written Premium]) as [Direct Ceded Written Premium],
        [begofmonth]
    FROM 
        #previousyear
    GROUP BY
        [Date],
        [Carrier],
        [begofmonth]

--Sum up the premiums for each day
INSERT INTO #currentyearAggregate
    SELECT
        [Date],
        [Carrier],
        SUM([Direct Ceded Written Premium]) as [Direct Ceded Written Premium],
        [begofmonth]
    FROM 
        #currentyear
    GROUP BY
        [Date],
        [Carrier],
        [begofmonth]

INSERT INTO #comparison_over_previous_year
    SELECT 
        cy.[Date], 
        cy.[Carrier],
        cy.[Direct Ceded Written Premium] - py.[Direct Ceded Written Premium],
        cy.[begofmonth]
    FROM
        #currentyearAggregate cy
    JOIN 
        #previousyearAggregate py ON 
        py.[Carrier] = cy.[Carrier] 
        and py.[Date] = cy.[Date]              --Added this join condition

--Selects the data in order to dump into SSRS
SELECT *
FROM #comparison_over_previous_year
```

Comment: This seems like it's in the right direction. Notice how I have a column that says begofmonth? I created that column in order to just aggregate everything by month instead of montha and day. It would make it easier to group by. SO for the month of January, There could be four carriers that did a transaction: Palomar, Palomar CA, Palomar WA, and Palomar OR. But they could not have done a transaction from last year. So I want to subtract the values per carrier, per month.

Comment: @Libson then just remove the [DATE] column from the SELECT and GROUP BY in the #aggregate tables, and change the JOIN in the last select to [begofmonth] instead of [date]

Comment: That's exactly what I did. The #aggregate tables are showing the right data but the #comparison_over_previous_year is off by a lot. I think selecting the month and year for the aggregation is throwing it off since I am only selecting the begofmonth from the #currentyearAggregate table. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also, joining on the begofmonth column is a no no since like I said, some carriers may not  have done transactions in some months. If you look at the excel screenshot above, Palomar Value Select CA did a transaction on January 2016 but did not on January 2015, therefore joining on this column is not good.

Comment: It shouldn't matter in the aggregation--but it's hard to tell what's happening on your end without test data. If you SUM by begofmonth then you'll have 1 row for each carrier for each begofmonth date (assuming you exclude the date column from the select). Then, join `OIN 
        #previousyearAggregate py ON 
        py.[Carrier] = cy.[Carrier] 
        and py.[begofmonth] = cy.[begofmonth]` should make this a 1 to 1 relation, unless there are some months missing for a carrier in one year to the next. i.e. Palomar has data for 1/1/2015 but not 1/1/2016 then it'd be ignored all together...

Comment: In this case, you need to use a date table so you can force a 0 for every month which there isn't data, in both years. You can handle this in the proc.

Comment: Or make this a full join instead of an inner join and use ISNULL on your subtraction.

Comment: Yes I am trying to force a data in both and force a zero for the premiums. I am trying to work things out and will update once done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275945/sql-how-do-i-generate-rows-for-each-month-based-on-date-ranges-in-existing-dat

Comment: i THINK i GOT IT. What I had to do was to use dateadd function on the join statement since begofmonth would not join due to previous year and current year. So I did py.[begofmonth] = dateadd(year, -1,cy.[begofmonth])  and it worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad this post helped @Libson

Answer (score 0):

Dateadd function cannot be used as parameter. you can declare a variable like this

```
Declare @ProcStartdate datetime = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@startdate)
Declare @ProcEnddate datetime = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@Enddate)

INSERT INTO #previousyear
EXECUTE [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] 

@ProcStartdate 
,@ProcEnddate 
,@ResEQCarrierCd = 'Palomar'
```

Comment: it doesn't work since atStartDate and atEndDate parameters are from the [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] I get the error below:
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "atStartDate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 48
Must declare the scalar variable "atProcStartdate".

Comment: atStartdate and atEnddate are used as parameter for [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518]. So your previous SP is assigning the values to atStartdate  and atEnddate.  This is what you told in your previous comment

Comment: That is correct. atStartDate and atEndDate are from [dbo].[rpt_written_premium_extract_CURRENT_YEAR_RPT-4518] so how to I go about executing those parameters? When I declare a new parameter like what you have above, it gives me an error saying I need to declare scalar variable atStartDate